Сделать из двух js обьектов массив обьектов
Дан массив обьектов, мне нужно его отфильтровать и вывести только те у которых ключ sex равняется male. Вывести нужно в массив. Я перебрал массив и получил два нужных обьекта, но не могу сделать из них массив.
let arrayOfObjects = [
    { name: "Ivan", age: 25, sex: "male" },
    { name: "Jessica", age: 37, sex: "female" },
    { name: "Steven", age: 18, sex: "male" },
    { name: "Caroline", age: 43, sex: "female" },
];

let array = [];

arrayOfObjects.forEach((elem)=> {
    if (elem.hasOwnProperty('sex') && elem.sex === 'male') {
        console.log(elem);
    }
})


у массивов есть метод push ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push )

Либо можно воспользоваться стандартным методом массивов filter для фильтрации

Используйте метод Array.prototype.filter() (документация)


let arrayOfObjects = [
    { name: "Ivan", age: 25, sex: "male" },
    { name: "Jessica", age: 37, sex: "female" },
    { name: "Steven", age: 18, sex: "male" },
    { name: "Caroline", age: 43, sex: "female" },
];

let array = arrayOfObjects.filter(item => item.sex === 'male');

console.log(array);



Если же вы хотите использовать свой способ, используйте Array.prototype.push() (Документация)


let arrayOfObjects = [
    { name: "Ivan", age: 25, sex: "male" },
    { name: "Jessica", age: 37, sex: "female" },
    { name: "Steven", age: 18, sex: "male" },
    { name: "Caroline", age: 43, sex: "female" },
];

let array = [];

arrayOfObjects.forEach((elem)=> {
    if (elem.hasOwnProperty('sex') && elem.sex === 'male') {
        array.push(elem);
    }
})

console.log(array);



